# Using ADF How to Copy Cosmos DB every record individually as complete JSON into a Single column in Azure SQL Table

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Using **ADF** how to **Copy Cosmos DB every record** individually as complete JSON into a Single column nvarchar(MAX) in Azure SQL Table

Answer (score 0):

Others have posted almost the same questions, per my experience, I tested and didn't find any way could load JSON data into one row nvarchar(MAX) in Azure SQL database table.

No document and blog talks about this,  I'm sorry that I can't give more evidences to prove it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have in Azure SQL DB table, a column named `jsondata` of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. You can specify the JSON path to map using the "Advanced editor" in the Mapping tab of the Copy activity. Be sure to check the "Map complex values to string" box. See below screenshot:

[image: Mapping for copy Cosmos DB record JSON to Azure SQL DB table NVARCHAR(MAX) column]